# Count of values for each distinct key

Tags: python, dictionary

My python code is like this:

```
d={'abc':'movies', 'abc': 'sports', 'abc': 'music', 'xyz': 'music', 'pqr':'music','pqr':'movies', 'pqr':'sports', 'pqr':'news', 'pqr':'sports'}

b=[j[0] for i in d for j in i.items()]

for k in list(set(b)):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(k, b.count(k))
```

I need to print number of distinct values per each key individually.
That means I would want to print

```
abc 3
xyz 1
pqr 4
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`
Please help!

Comment: is you dictionary valid ? it cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: The below answers perfectly answer your question, please consider accepting the answer that helped you resolve your issue best.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that, because each key can appear only once in a dictionary:

```
>>> d={'abc':'movies', 'abc': 'sports', 'abc': 'music', 'xyz': 'music', 'pqr':'music','pqr':'movies', 'pqr':'sports', 'pqr':'news', 'pqr':'sports'}
>>> d
{'pqr': 'sports', 'abc': 'music', 'xyz': 'music'}
```

What you want is to have `list`s as values:

```
>>> d = {'abc': ['movies', 'sports', 'music'], 'xyz': ['music'], 'pqr': ['music', 'movies', 'sports', 'news', 'sports']}
>>> d
{'xyz': ['music'], 'abc': ['movies', 'sports', 'music'], 'pqr': ['music', 'movies', 'sports', 'news', 'sports']}
```

With this representation it's pretty simple to do what you want:

```
>>> for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
...     print key, len(value)   #in python3: print(key, len(value))
... 
abc 3
pqr 5
xyz 1
```

If you then want to add a value to a given key simply do:

```
>>> d['xyz'].append('news')
>>> for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
...     print key, len(value)
... 
abc 3
pqr 5
xyz 2
```

Often in this kind of circumstances using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a plain `dict` is better.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary in Python:

```
>>> d = {'abc':'movies', 'abc': 'sports', 'abc': 'music', 'xyz': 'music', 'pqr':'music','pqr':'movies', 'pqr':'sports', 'pqr':'news', 'pqr':'sports'}
>>> print d
{'pqr': 'sports', 'abc': 'music', 'xyz': 'music'}
```